# Querying a JSON array in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table with json field

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
                      ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                      info json NOT NULL
);
```

I inserted data to it

```
INSERT INTO orders (info)
VALUES
(
  '{"interestedIn":[11,12,13],"countries":["US", "UK"]}'
);
```

How can I get rows where `intrestedIn` in(11, 12) and `countries` in("US")?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `jsonb` is preferred over `json`

Comment: postgres version is 9.6

Comment: Consider upgrading pretty soon PostgreSQL devs stops supporting your version next year in november meaning no patches for performance and or security after that

Answer (score 1):

Your use of "in" in the problem specification is confusing, as you seem to be using it in some SQL-like pseudo syntax, but not with the same meaning it has SQL.

If you want rows where one of the countries is US and where both 11 and 12 are contained in "interestedIn", then it can be done in a single containment operation:

```
select * from orders where info::jsonb @> '{"interestedIn":[11,12],"countries":["US"]}'
```

If you want something other than that, then please explain in more detail, and provide both examples which should match and examples which should not match (and tell us which is which).

Answer (score 0):

Checking for the country is quite simple as that is a text value:

```
select *
from orders
where info::jsonb -> 'countries' ? 'US'
```

Adding the condition for the integer value is a bit more complicated because the `?` operator only works with strings. So you need to unnest the array:

```sql
select o.*
from orders o
where o.info::Jsonb -> 'countries' ? 'US'
  and exists (select *
              from json_array_elements_text(o.info -> 'interestedIn') as x(id)
              where x.id in ('11','12'));
```

If you also might need to check for multiple country values, you can use the `?|` operator:

```sql
select o.*
from orders o
where o.info::jsonb -> 'countries' ?| array['US', 'UK']
  and exists (select *
              from json_array_elements_text(o.info -> 'interestedIn') as x(id)
              where x.id in ('11','12'));
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/GSDTOH43863